# What is the natural projection of a partition?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

According to the text provided by my teacher, "any partition $P$ equals the natural partition of its natural projection, $P = P_p$" (to be proven as an exercise). Above this line, the text states that "given any partition $P$ of $X$, we can induce the natural projection of $X$ onto $P$, $p$ : $X \rightarrow P$ satisfying $p$ : $x \mapsto [x$]."

If the natural projection $p$ requires two sets, an original set X and a partition P such that $p$ : $X \rightarrow P$ satisfying $p$ : $x \mapsto [x$], then what does the phrase "its natural projection" in the first line refer to – what is the natural projection of a partition?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f\colon X \to Y$ is a function between sets, then $f$ induces a partition on $X$. Namely, $X$ is the disjoint union of the fibers of $f$ (a "fiber" is the inverse image of a single point in $Y$). Concretely: $$X = \bigcup_{y\in Y} f^{-1}(y).$$We can call this partition $P_f$.

Now, what happens is that if $X$ is a set with a partition $P$, then one has a natural map $p\colon X \to P$, which takes $x\in X$ to the element in $P$ to which $x$ belongs. The claim is that $P = P_p$.

**Big hint:** what is the inverse image under $p$ of an element of $P$?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the inverse image of an element of P under p should be the element of P itself, right?

Comment: Yes!!! In other words, the $p$-fiber of an element of $P$ is... itself (regarded now as a subset of $X$). Hence...?

Comment: The claim then must be true? For example, given a set $X$ = {1, 2, 3} and partition $P$ = {{1}, {2, 3}}, then $p$ maps 1 to {1} and 2, 3 to {2, 3}. Then the natural partition of p, or $P_p$ would be $p^{-1}$(Im($p$)) which is $p^{-1}$({{1}, {2, 3}}) = {{1}, {2, 3}} or $P$ itself.

Comment: That's the idea.

Comment: I'm trying to tackle the proof. Given that $P$ is a partition of a set X such that $P = \{[x] : x \in X\}$ and the natural partition of the domain of a function f is $P_f = f^{-1}(\text{Im}(f))$, then to prove $P = P_p$:

$P = P_p \implies P = p^{-1}(\text{Im}(p)) \implies P = \{p^{-1}(y): y \in \text{Im}(p)\}$.

I'm not really sure where to go from the third statement.